# Excel Array: Reducing the Number of Calculation Steps

Tags: arrays, excel

As per my on-going journey through the world of Excel arrays, I was wondering if someone might be able to give me a pointer or two.

On the excel sheet attached, I currently have a four-step process to get from a segregated lookup to a gapless list:

Step 1 (yellow): For the 50-word long list in sheet 'Data', a 50-cell lookup is performed to see whether the input in row 1 (red) appears somewhere in the corresponding cell. In this case, the lookup is performed three times for three different inputs, i.e. in columns C-E.

Step 2 (orange): An array then relists the contents of the 50-cell lookup above it but removes all empty cells (i.e. where there is no match to the input in row 1)

Step 3 (green): The results from step 2 are listed out in a single column.

Step 4 (blue): The results from step 3 are listed out using the same technique as in step 2 in order to remove the blank cells.

Collectively, this enables a gapless listing of all data objects which contain the given inputs somewhere in their string.

However, my real list of data objects is 5000 entries long and I would like to look up the results for 100 or more inputs. As step 1 requires each combination to be looked up separately, this requires 500,000 calculations for step 1 alone, which causes a heavy toll on the processors.

Therefore, I was wondering if anyone had an idea as to how I could shortcut this process to reduce the number of cells / calculations involved. I assume that step 1 and 2 could somehow be merged, but my knowledge of arrays is not sufficient to think of how this could be done.

It would be brilliant to hear from somebody who may have some advice on the matter!

Kind regards,
Rob

File Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10O91QDD78RkbWtQx2iWfax17Dt5TPw1G

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not removing duplicated entries from the final list, this is quite straightforward.

Based on the workbook you provided, to be entered within the *Lookup* sheet:

In cell `A1`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+ISNUMBER(FIND(C1:E1,Data!A1:A50)))`

In any cell of your choice, to begin the list of returns, **array formula****:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>A$1,"",INDIRECT("'Data'!"&TEXT(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(C$1:E$1,Data!A$1:A$50)),10^5*ROW(Data!A$1:A$50)+COLUMN(Data!A$1:A$50)),ROWS($1:1)),"R0C00000"),0))`

and copied down until you start to get blanks for the results.

**Notes:**

  Instructions for entering an array formula are at the foot of this post.

  The sheet name (emboldened within the second formula) should be amended as required.

  It is important that the range containing the values being searched for (
  `A1:C1`
  here) and that containing the entries to be searched within (
  `A1:A50`
  ) be orthogonal, i.e. one is a horizontal range, the other a vertical range.

  If you are not using an English-language version of Excel then the part
  `"R0C00000"`
  within the second formula may need amending.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Wowza! That is amazing! Thanks ever so much. I shall have to depict this to see what is happening as that is pretty powerful stuff. At the moment, I can't seem to see what order the results are coming out in. Is there any way of getting the order to be the same as would be the case for the original process? i.e. going down the columns from left to right? (Update: it would appear that the order is currently row by row across the columns, rather than column by column)

Comment: You're correct. It requires a little more work to have the results returned in a column-wise fashion, though it can be done. Case of formula efficiency versus output preference, though please let me know.

Comment: Well, if it can be done and it isn't too much of a hassle, then I'd be very interested. However, that being said, this has already taken out several thousand calculations as-is, so no worries if it is a pain! :-)

Comment: In case you fancy knowing, the calculation time on my workbook has now been reduced from about 90 seconds to 3-4 seconds. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Apologies - something came up. Will try to post column-wise solution when I get chance.